# how test all the possible outcomes of a formula in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I have written a formula and I wanted to know how can I test all the outcomes of the formula for all real numbers (or a specific range). Also I wanted to know if I could plot the outcomes with `matplotlib`
my formula is `x = freq / t * 2`

`X` is the output `freq` is the frequency change and `t` is time. `freq` can be between `75 to 300` and `t` is mostly from `0 to 5`

I had written this code in Python but I have to change it for every possibility of the variables.

I use python 3.4 btw

```
freq = -80
t = 5
x = freq / t * 2
print (x)
```

Edit: I wrote the code for intuition.

Comment: Read the docs. Write a function. Run the function.

Comment: You cannot test all the possible outcomes. Read about [unit testing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html). Unit testing is designed to verify exact inputs with their exact outcomes.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've tried writing a function but still it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Then post it here. Also, have you tried evaluating on a grid of inputs for each variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy's `meshgrid` makes it really easy to compute a function at every point on an N-d grid:

```
import numpy as np

# introduce bases
freq_min, freq_max, freq_spacing = 75., 300., 5.
freqs = np.arange(freq_min, freq_max + freq_spacing, freq_spacing)

t_min, t_max, t_spacing = 0.1, 5., 0.1
ts = np.arange(t_min, t_max + t_spacing, t_spacing)

# do calculation
F, T = np.meshgrid(freqs, ts)
Z = F / T * 2
```

then we can plot it like

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# display result
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(F, T, Z,
    rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.RdPu, antialiased=True, linewidth=0.2)
ax.view_init(elev=35, azim=160)
ax.dist = 10
plt.show()
```

which produces

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First, there are either zero, one, or infinitely many real numbers within a range.  You cannot test a function over any non-trivial range of real numbers, although you could generate a mathematical proof that the function will work over that range.  That pedantry aside, what you want is nestled loops:

```
freq = 75.0
while freq <= 500.0:
    t = 0.5
    while t <= 5.0:
        x = freq / t * 2
        print '%f\t%f\t%f' % (freq, t, x)
        t += 0.5
    freq += 25.0
```

Note that t cannot be exactly zero.

Comment: That will **compute** approximately all the possible results. Not **test** them.

Comment: What is meant by *test* in the original question is unclear; I am responding to "I had written this code in Python but I have to change it for every possibility of the variables" with the caveat that sampling *every* value is impossible.  However, the OP wants to plot outcomes and the sort of sampling I propose should be sufficient for that purpose.

Comment: First of all, to me it looks like the OP has spent no time trying to do his own research. The question is poorly formulated and there are innumerous grammatical oversights. As far as the "question" is concerned of the OP, it seems like he has 2 of them. The first one asks for "how test all the possible outcomes...". The answer to question 1:  **There is no sensible way or reason for trying to test every real number in that range**. The second question is, "If I could plot the outcomes with `matplotlib`", and the answer to the 2nd question: **Yes**.

Comment: @QaziPython I have searched and I could do the same in Matlab but  wanted to use Python for some reasons. for question number 1 as you said `` There is no sensible way or reason for trying to test every real number in that range`` what @user2752364 mentioned is sufficient and works good.
about the second question I know that I can plot it. but how can I plot the result simultaneously

Comment: @user2752364 Great answer thanks +1